# Using loop to convert multiple files into separate files

Tags: loops, for-loop, converters, cat, tcpdump

I used this command to convert multiple pcap log files to text using tcpdump :

```
$ cat /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.* | tcpdump -n -r - > /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2/bigfile.txt
```

and it worked well.

Now I want to separate the output, each converted file in a separate output file using loop like this :

```
for f in /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.* ; do
tcpdump -n -r "$f" > /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2/"$f.txt" ; 
done
```

But it gave me :

```
bash: /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2//home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1485894664.txt: No such file or directory
bash: /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2//home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1485894770.txt: No such file or directory
bash: /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2//home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1487346947.txt: No such file or directory
```

I think the problem in $f, Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
for f in /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.* ; do
    echo $f
done
```

You'll find that you're getting

```
/home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1485894664
/home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1485894770
/home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.1487346947
```

You can use `basename`

To get only the filename, something like this:

```
for f in /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.* ; do
    base="$(basename $f)"
    echo $base
done
```

Once you're satisfied that this is working, remove the echo statement and use

```
tcpdump -n -r "$f" > /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2/"$base.txt"
```

instead.

Edit: `tcpdump -n -r "$base" > ...` should have been `tcpdump -n -r "$f" > ...`; you only want to use `$base` in the context of creating the new filename, not in the context of reading the existing data.

Comment: I did as you said and it's worked, until the last one,when i used this:# for f in /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs/snort.log.* ; do
 base="$(basename $f)"
 tcpdump -n -r "$base" > /home/dalya/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs2/"$base.txt"
 done .
It gave me this :
tcpdump: snort.log.1485894664: No such file or directory
tcpdump: snort.log.1485894770: No such file or directory
tcpdump: snort.log.1487346947: No such file or directory
tcpdump: truncated dump file; tried to read 4 file header bytes, only got 0